# I want to set CLASSPATH for java using a shell script on OS X

Tags: java, bash, shell, classpath

File - "path.txt" is saving all my CLASSPATH locations in perfect syntax. My Script is able to get the data from the file but unable to update the CLASSPATH in terminal.

I have tried using double quotes around $value
export CLASSPATH="$VALUE"

```
value=$(<~/Downloads/Karan/path.txt)
clear
echo $value
export CLASSPATH=$value
```

Expected output on terminal for
**echo $CLASSPATH** should be the value returned by **$value** but there is **NO CHANGE in CLASSPATH and NO ERROR**

Comment: How are you running this? If you are running it as a shell script - environment variables are only available to that process and its children. If you want the lines to run *in the current shell* you have to run it using `source` or `.`.

Comment: That did it... Thank you @RealSkeptic ...